# How to load more posts from JSON object after the initial call using jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wordpress, phonegap-build

I am in the process of building a mobile app for a blog. We are going to be using phonegap build and build the project using html, css, jquery. Our blog is a wordpress setup and we are wanting to pull the posts into the app using the JSON API plugin.

We have the JSON API plugin working and the posts are being pulled into the app just fine. Our problem is that we would like to initially only load 10 posts (with a ?count=n) and then load an additional 10 each time they either: a) click a load more button, or b) scroll to the bottom of the page.

We have been able to set up and trigger the click and scroll options but haven't figured out how to get the next sequential posts into the post without first emptying the page and doing a fresh load of posts by updating the "?count=" with the desired value.

Here is our ajax call:

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'http://linkarati.com/api/get_recent_posts/?count=10&callback=?',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      $(data.posts).each(function(i,v){
        $('#posts').append('<div class="post"><img src="'+v.thumbnail+'"/><div class="text"><h2>'+v.title+'</h2><p>'+v.excerpt+'</p></div></div>');
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SjoerdDeWit your code is fine, but he should use the page parameter, not the count parameter for that. According to your example this would look like this:

```
var i = 0;
function ajaxCall(){

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://linkarati.com/api/get_recent_posts/?count=10&page='+i+'&callback=?',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $(data.posts).each(function(i,v){
            $('#posts').append('<div class="post"><img src="'+v.thumbnail+'"/><div class="text"><h2>'+
            v.title+'</h2><p>'+v.excerpt+'</p></div></div>');
        });
        i++;
    }
});
```

}

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts for more information on the parameters that can be used.

Edit:

Sorry the API uses the page parameter, not the offset parameter - I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should put it in a function which you call on the loadmore or scroll infinite: then you can increment an int with 10 posts which u use in your php part to set the limit

```
var i = 10;
function ajaxCall(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://linkarati.com/api/get_recent_posts/?count='+i+'&callback=?',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $(data.posts).each(function(i,v){
                $('#posts').append('<div class="post"><img src="'+v.thumbnail+'"/><div class="text"><h2>'+
                v.title+'</h2><p>'+v.excerpt+'</p></div></div>');
            });
            i = i+10;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this would lead to loading all the previous posts with every subsequent call - means after 10 clicks you will load a hundred posts.